# Why jQuery code not called here...please suggest?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Below all my code,

**Model **

Below is Model code,

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int? Year { get; set; }
    public int? Month { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Years
    {
        get
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(2000, 12).Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.ToString(),
                Text = x.ToString()
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

Below is Controller code,

```
//
    // GET: /MenuSix/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Months(int year)
    {
        if (year == 2011)
        {
            return Json(
                Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(x => new { value = x, text = x }),
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            );
        }
        return Json(
            Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(x => new { value = x, text = x }),
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        );
    }
```

**View**

Below is View code,

```
@model DemoWeb.Models.MenuSix.MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.DropDownListFor(
x => x.Year,
new SelectList(Model.Years, "Value", "Text"),
"-- select year --"
)
@Html.DropDownListFor(
x => x.Month,
Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),
"-- select month --"
)
}

@section PageScriptsAndCSS{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Year').change(function () {
        debugger;
        var selectedYear = $(this).val();
        if (selectedYear != null && selectedYear != '') {
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Months")', { year: selectedYear }, 
 function    (months) {
                var monthsSelect = $('#Month');
                monthsSelect.empty();
                $.each(months, function (index, month) {
                    monthsSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                        value: month.value,
                        text: month.text
                    }));
                });
            });
        }
    });

</script>
}
```

I'm testing above code, but in jquery code not called here, please suggest why the dropdown change event not called in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the javascript code in document.ready to ensure that control is available when binding then event. IT looks this javascript is rendered at the head and at that point drop down is not yet added to the DOM

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

{
 $("#year").///rest of the code
});